# Conditional Sorting according to one value and then alphabetically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have this group in a table. Where I need to display one value on the top and rest according to its alphabetical order.

**Table**

```
     Column1      Value#1  Value#2

     Alpha         12      26
     Beta          65     745
     Gamma        987      87
     Pie            7       2
     Non-Beta     132     426
     Zeta         112     266
```

I want to sort it like this(Can anyone also tell me the real use of this other than Viewing Purpose)

**Table**

```
    Column1      Value#1  Value#2

     Non-Beta     132     426
     Alpha         12      26
     Beta          65     745
     Gamma        987      87
     Pie            7       2
     Zeta         112     266
```

So the **Non-Beta** has to be displayed on the top and rest according to alphabetical order.

**Edit**

Thank you very much for the below reply Chris, Really appreciate and yes it works. 
I have one more question from the over table format itself...How can I display it in the below format...

**Table**

```
    Column1      Value#1  Value#2

     Non-Beta     132     426
     Alpha         12      26
     Pie            7       2
     Zeta         112     266
      Total       263     720

     Beta          65     745
     Gamma        987      87
      Total       1057    832
```

Thank you

Comment: In the above edit, I am trying to create  flag for 'Beta' and 'Gamma' and then use that flag to create in another column in sql query itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the table, right-click the table handle, select `Tablix Properties` and select the `Sorting` tab. Press the `Add` button then click the `fx` button to open the expression editor. Enter the following expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Column1.Value = "Non-Beta", "A" + Fields!Column1.Value, "B" + Fields!Column1.Value)
```

All we are doing is prefixing the special value field with something so it comes before the other fields.

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you very much for the above answer. But what if I want to have everything to the order I Specify. Is there a way to do it.(Like in the order of : Non-Beta,Zeta,Alpha and Pie)

Comment: I tried =IIF(Fields!Column1.Value = "Non-Beta",Fields!Column1.Value ="Zeta",Fields!Column1.Value="Alpha",Fields!Column1.Value="Pie") But it did not work .The report is throwing an error

Comment: That's because your function parameters for `IIF` are wrong. It needs to have three parameters `=IIF(condition, valueiftrue, valueiffalse)` and you not only have four parameters, they are all conditionals. It looks like you would be better served by the `SWITCH` function like so: `=SWITCH(Fields.Column1.Value = "Non-Beta", "A", Fields.Column1.Value = "Alpha", "B", Fields.Column1.Value = "Pie", "C")`